# Typescript resulting in cannot find module error

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I am trying to build a basic Express api and am running in to an odd `module not found` error. Before introducing TypeScript to my project, I never got this error. This has been quite frustrating to resolve. I appreciate any suggestions on why I am getting this error and how to resolve.

server.ts

```
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
//import * as api from "api"; also tried this

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));

app.use('/api', require('./api'));

app.use('*', (req, res, next) => {
    let error = new Error('404: not found');
    next(error);
});

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(500).send({
        error: {
            message: error.message
        }
    });
});

const port = 3000;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('listening on port', port);
});

module.exports = app;
```

api/api.ts

```
import express from "express";

const router = express.Router();

router.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
   res.send('cool');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With typescript, we don't use module.exports but export directly like so:

```
import express from "express";

export const router = express.Router();

router.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
   res.send('cool');
});
```

Then we can get the router with

```
import {router} from './api'
```